# Failed Login Session in Twitter Connect Plugin for Ionic 3

Tags: twitter, ionic3, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use [Twitter Connect](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/twitter-connect/) plugin with **firebase** for my Ionic 3 application. It was working perfect but now it is throwing **Failed Login Session** error in the console.

In **package.json**:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@ionic-native/twitter-connect": "^4.19.0",
    "twitter-connect-plugin": "git+https://github.com/chroa/twitter-connect-plugin.git",
  },
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "twitter-connect-plugin": {
        "FABRIC_KEY": "********************",
        "TWITTER_KEY": "****************",
        "TWITTER_SECRET": "******************"
      }
    }
  }
```

In **config.xml**:

```
<plugin name="twitter-connect-plugin" spec="https://github.com/chroa/twitter-connect-plugin">
    <variable name="FABRIC_KEY" value="***********" />
    <variable name="TWITTER_KEY" value="***********" />
    <variable name="TWITTER_SECRET" value="*************" />
</plugin>
```

I have checked all the keys and they are all correct. Can anyone point me what is the problem here?